# Can't rename files, or name new files that have the letter "O"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had this on just my windows machine at first so I figured it was a local issue, but now I'm seeing it on my mac as well. I am trying to rename a folder or a file but anytime I press the "O" key while naming it, it instead types nothing but rather opens/closes the folder I'm renaming. How do I fix this?

Comment: Let go of the CTRL key?

Comment: Doesn't actually open it in finder, it just expands it in the explorer view. Super helpful comment though ;p.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue related to my vim plugin I was using. Disabling it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing exactly same issue. In my case it was happening for any name and not just letter `O`. On pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> I could type a new name but on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it would have no effect at all.

[image]

It would continue showing up the old directory name. Visual Studio (VS) Code doesn't throw any error to suggest why it was happening. Then I realized that I was running an NPM server from the same root folder `HELLO-WORLD`. So the NPM server process might have been using the `test` directory(within `HELLO-WORLD` folder) that I was trying to rename.

When I tried to rename the same folder from Windows Explorer then it gave me the actual error that the directory was in use by some process. I stopped the NPM server and it got resolved. Thereafter, I was able to rename the directory from VS Code as well.